# Get Root Website URL in REST API

Tags: rest

How to get SharePoint Root Website or parent web site URL in REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
```

Comment: which on Can Get the Root web URL

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; it is working

Answer (score 3):

Just make a GET request to the following `URL`

```
/_api/Web?$select=ParentWeb&$expand=ParentWeb
```

You will get all information about it's parent web. Example of a response:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "Web",
            "uri": "http://yoursite/_api/Web",
            "type": "SP.Web"
        },
        "ParentWeb": {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "Web/ParentWeb",
                "uri": "http://yoursite/_api/Web/ParentWeb",
                "type": "SP.WebInformation"
            },
            "Configuration": 1,
            "Created": "2015-08-20T03:54:12",
            "Description": "",
            "Id": "f5e038cc-455c-425a-9afd-57b37eb8d7f1",
            "Language": 1033,
            "LastItemModifiedDate": "2015-10-21T06:18:21Z",
            "ServerRelativeUrl": "/",
            "Title": "Intranet",
            "WebTemplate": "STS",
            "WebTemplateId": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Following code snippet is the example using jQuery

```
    function getParentWebInfo(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var parentWebUrl = data.d.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the root site of the site collection, it's:

```
/_api/Site/RootWeb
```